# Rendering Table in React using Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I really hope you can help me.  I am essentially trying to render the following using React and Firebase to a webpage.  This is just for read access for the end user (I will want filters and searches on at a later date).

[image: Data I am trying to upload]

I have the following data in Firebase.

[Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUcOx.png)

If there is a better way to have this in Firebase then I would be open to ideas.

I have written the following code which renders my data using a JSON object and gives me the result I want.

My question is how do I write this code to incorporate the firebase database I have described?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

export function stockdata() {
  return [{
    "Close" : 5.25,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "VOXX"
  }, {
    "Close" : 14.97,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "BVDRF"
  }, {
    "Close" : 59.16,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "JBSS"
  }, {
    "Close" : 82.04,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "MGPI"
  }, {
    "Close" : 47.59,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "SMP"
  }, {
    "Close" : 41.35,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "ADM"
  }, {
    "Close" : 16.46,
    "DateofAnalysis" : "2018-08-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "Ticker" : "FUJHY"
  } ]
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        json: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      json: stock()
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Close</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Ticker</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>{data.Close}</td>
                                <td>{data.DateofAnalysis}</td>
                                <td>{data.Ticker}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: This is a Cascading Style Sheets and/or HTML `<table>` question, maybe how to iterate over array/object in JS, and is unrelated to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks Ron I have framed this better to be more focused on firebase I hope you can help me...